# CMake cannot find GLEW library

Tags: cmake, linker, glew

I have an issue with building CMake project with GLEW. Following the solved issues with similar names on this site, I have landed on the following CmakeLists.txt:

```
set(GLEW_DIR "ext/glew-2.2.0")

set(GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR "ext/glew-2.2.0/include")
set(GLEW_LIBRARY "ext/glew-2.2.0/lib/Release/Win32")
set(GLEW_LIBRARIES "ext/glew-2.2.0/lib/Release/x64/glew32")

# Find OpenGL package (required for GLEW)
#find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(engine PUBLIC kgfw PUBLIC glfw PUBLIC glm box2d PUBLIC freetype PUBLIC glfont PUBLIC ${GLEW_LIBRARY}
```

error:

> Could NOT find GLEW (missing: GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS GLEW_LIBRARIES)
> CMakeLists.txt:47 (find_package)

Removing find_package allows it to generate, but gives compile error:

> Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'ext\glew 2.2.0\lib\Release\Win32.lib'

This is the correct file location, yet the library isn't found. I am stuck. I have downloaded 2.2.0 from the official site. Is there something I am missing? Wikihow and other tutorials online do not seem to hit this hurdle, their examples not running either.

Comment: Documentation for [FindGLEW](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGLEW.html) doesn't list possible hints, so settings like `GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR`, `GLEW_LIBRARIES` is not the way to go. There is standard setting of `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable which could help: `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glew-2.2.0)` (note on using **absolute** path).

Comment: "This is the correct file location, yet the library isn't found." - No, the path `ext\glew 2.2.0\lib\Release\Win32.lib` is NOT a correct location of a file: note on the `.lib` extension. A parameter for `target_link_libraries` should be a library (**file**), but the path `ext/glew-2.2.0/lib/Release/Win32` is a **directory**. Do NOT pass **directories** to `target_link_libraries` and do NOT assign **directories** to CMake variables ended with `_LIBRARY` or `_LIBRARIES`: thiese suffixes of variables normally means, that they should contain libraries, not directories.

Comment: @Tsyvarev What is the correct location of the file?

Comment: Do you ask me where the library files are located on **your machine**? Just look into `ext\glew 2.2.0\lib\Release\Win32` directory and find a file which has `.lib` extension.

Answer (score -2):

Solution is to have the following CMakeLists:

```
set(GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR "ext/glew-2.2.0/include")

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glew-2.2.0)

target_link_libraries(engine PUBLIC ${GLEW_LIBRARY})
```